# Using verbs correctly when mixing past and future tenses

Tags: grammar, tenses

A: Why did you call me last night?

B: I just **wanted** to know if I **could** use your car when/whenever my girlfriend **asks** me to pick her up at her home.

I would like to know if the verbs in bold are in the correct tense.

Answer (score 2):

In general you shouldn't switch from one tense to another unless the timing of an action demands that you do.

> I just **wanted** to know if I **could** use your car when/whenever my girlfriend **asks** me to pick her up at her home.

In your dialogue, `Person B` establishes the past-tense. The verbs `Person A` uses: **wanted**
and **could** are both past-tense (so correct). The verb **asks** is not, but this is still correct because it is preceded by **when/whenever**.

This means that `Person A's` girlfriend is subject to **ask(s)** at any time (including the past, present, and future); thus, it is correct. If you were to use the past tense (**asked**), that would be incorrect because it doesn't cover the present and future.

Comment: Let's say the time when his girlfriend asked him to pick her up is yesterday and the conversation is taking place now. You should *asked* as the girlfriend **asked in the past**. Also, you cannot use whenever in the sentence. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Rathony In that case it would be: *I just wanted to know if I might have been able to have used the car to pick up Jane from the station last night. But it turned out all right, I managed to get a taxi*. One could use *could have* instead of *might have been able to have*, but in this particular time context it does not sound especially polite.

Comment: @WS2 In that case, I would have used "in the future" at the end of the sentence to make it clear. BTW, how many people are lending his car for his friend whenever he askes for a car whenever her girlfreind askes him to pick her up at "**home"**. I would not once in my lifetime unless she is lost in a desert.

Comment: @Rathony I don't understand why you would have said *in the future*. Nothing in the sentence is about the future.

Comment: @WS2 If "whenever" is used in the sentence, it indicates "*more strongly than when*" an action (to ask me to pick her up) in the future.

Comment: @Rathony But in your first comment you asked what would be the case 'when the time was yesterday'. In that situation one would not use *when* or *whenever*.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, that's right.